# How to mock an dependency when passed as an argument?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

We created a common class where a RestTemplate is passed as a parameter. This rest template is used to facilitate:

- postForEntity
- exchange

However, since it is not Autowired in the common class, I am not able to create unit tests that mocks the RestTemplate. Is there a work around for this?

Setup:

Spring boot Project A - initiates a rest integration and utilises the common class. This Project A instantiates the @Autowired RestTemplate rest template and pass it as a parameter to the common class method.

Spring boot Common Class - conducts the rest integration but uses the rest template passed by Project A. This common class I am unable to conduct the unit test since I cannot mock the Rest Template.

This is a java spring boot project.

Addendum:

**COMMON CLASS

```java
public class RestService {


     public static void invoke(RestTemplate restTemplate, RequestDetails requestDetails) {

      switch (requestDetails.getHttpMethod()) {
            case POST:
                HttpEntity<?> postEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, httpHeaders);
                restResponse = restTemplate.postForEntity(requestDetails.getUrl(), postEntity, String.class);
                break;
            case GET:
                HttpEntity<?> getEntity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
                restResponse = restTemplate.exchange(requestDetails.getUrl(),
                    HttpMethod.GET, getEntity, String.class);
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }

    }

}
```

** INVOKING CLASS

```java
public class InvokingClass {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


     public void invoke() {

     //RequestDetails construct here ...

        RestService.invoke(restTemplate,requestDetails)
    }

}
```

Comment: Could we get a [mcve] please?

Comment: hi sir @Robert, for your reference added some codes that i tried to simplify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to test your `RestService` you should be able to do something like this:

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        RestTemplate templateMock = mock(RestTemplate.class);
        RestService.invoke(templateMock, new RequestDetails());
        verify(templateMock).postForEntity(any(URI.class), any(Object.class), any(Class.class));
    }
```

If this is not what you're looking for please provide more details on what you're trying to test. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tomaz! This actually allowed me to execute my test cases successfully. I just used templateMock and add this in my setup in @Before

Comment: private RestTemplate        mockTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockTemplate = mock(RestTemplate.class);
    }